# Select records with at one day in centain year

Tags: excel, date

I want to make a selection of records where date range (start date - end date) includes at least 1 day of 2020. So for example: if a record has 2018-01-13 as the start date and 2020-01-09 as end date, it has to be included in my selection, as there is at least one day active in 2020.
Sample data:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe include screenshots or sample data of your input and expected output. Does "include" mean "physically select" as in drag your cursor? Very unclear what you're *actually* trying to do.

Comment: I want to make a subset of the data

Comment: Use Power Query

Answer (score 2):

Just check the years with the standard between notation

> **Start Year <= 2020 <= End Year**

---

```
=AND(YEAR(A1)<=2020,YEAR(B1)>=2020)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(OR(YEAR(A2)=2020,YEAR(B2)=2020),1,0)
```

Comment: A brief explanation on why this code match the question will be great!

Answer (score -2):

Excel store dates as numbers, so, you must compare them like numbers

Make a column with: `=IF(OR(B2 < $C$2; $D$2 < A2); 0; 1)`
where

1. A: start date
2. B: final date
3. C: 2020-01-01
4. D: 2020-12-31

, Now you can use only values 1

Comment: Please, use English formulas. If I understood it correctly it should be `=IF(OR(B2 < $C$2; $D$2 < A2); 0; 1)`